# Can this if statment be simplified?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

```
   for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for (int j = i; j < a.length; j++) {
        if (a[j] % 2 == 0 && i % 2 == 0 ||
            a[j] % 2 == 1 && i % 2 == 1)
```

To give some context, this is looking through two for loops for even and odd numbers

Comment: looks like that's the same as `if (a[j] %2 == i % 2)`

Comment: if  `a` is an intenger array, it can be simplified to `if (a[j] == i) `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `if (a[j] % 2 == i % 2)`, as you're just checking if the parity is the same.